# Error a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

Tags: c++

```
void main1()    
{

    const int MAX = 50;

    class infix
    {

    private:

            char target[MAX], stack[MAX];
            char *s, *t;
            int top, l;
        public:
            infix( );
            void setexpr ( char *str );
            void push ( char c );
            char pop( );
            void convert( );
            int priority ( char c );
            void show( );
    };
    void infix :: infix( ) //error
    {
        top = -1;
        strcpy ( target, "" );
        strcpy ( stack, "" );
        l = 0;
    }
    void infix :: setexpr ( char *str )//error
    {
        s = str;
        strrev ( s );
        l = strlen ( s );
        * ( target + l ) = '\0';
        t = target + ( l - 1 );
    }
    void infix :: push ( char c )//error
    {
        if ( top == MAX - 1 )
            cout << "\nStack is full\n";
        else
        {
            top++ ;
            stack[top] = c;
        }
    }
}
```

I am having trouble with this code. This is a part of my code for infix to prefix converter. My compiler keeps giving me the error:

> "A function-declaration is not allowed here – before '{' token"

There's actually three errors in this project. My project is due in September 2015, so please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Move the class and it's functions to the outside of the main1 function.

Answer (score 11):

You have your classes' function definitions inside your `main` function, which is not allowed. To fix that, you should place them outside, but to do that you will need to place the whole class outside of main as well (since you need it to be in scope):

```
class A
{
public:
    void foo();
};

void A::foo()
{
    <...>
}

int main()
{
    <...>
}
```

It's worth noting that, while it is possible to put the whole class definition inside your main, this is not the best approach:

```
int main()
{
    class A
    {
    public:
        void foo()
        {
            <...>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where would i place  const int MAX = 50 ;

Comment: @Clones, if you only use it in the class, you should make it a class member.

Comment: new errors occurred to me.
"top, target, and strcpy was not declared in this scope"
it says

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a closing `}` for the main function.

Comment: that must be typo in this question.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the code below:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string.h>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 50 ;

class infix
{

private :

        char target[MAX], stack[MAX] ;
        char *s, *t ;
        int top, l ;
    public :
        infix() ;
        void setexpr ( char *str ) ;
        void push ( char c ) ;
        char pop( ) ;
        void convert( ) ;
        int priority ( char c ) ;
        void show( ) ;
};
infix::infix() //error
{
    top = -1 ;
    strcpy ( target, "" ) ;
    strcpy ( stack, "" ) ;
    l = 0 ;
}
void infix :: setexpr ( char *str )//error
{
    s = str ;
 //   strrev ( s ) ;
    l = strlen ( s ) ;
    * ( target + l ) = '\0' ;
    t = target + ( l - 1 ) ;
}
void infix :: push ( char c )//error
{
    if ( top == MAX - 1 )
        cout << "\nStack is full\n" ;
    else
    {
        top++ ;
        stack[top] = c ;
    }
}

int main()
{
     /* call your function from here*/
}
```