# What does this mean: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

Tags: c++

My problem is at in the C++ lines below, but I just can't figure it out.

> [Error] a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    void displaymenu(){
        cout<<"MENU"<<"\n";
    }
    displaymenu();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot define functions inside a function.  You might need to revisit [how to create functions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_functions.htm)

Comment: Dude.  I'm not going to try to read this!

Comment: When reporting compilation errors or run-time errors it's important to include the error position too (the line of code in execution when the error arose)!

Comment: People are downvoting because questions of the form "here's my code, make it work" are not very welcome here. You should ask a concise question that can be answered. Here, someone first has to look through everything, find *your* error and then explain how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot to add the lines I had trouble in at the end of the code. first time using the code thing and it didn't add what i couldn't understand with it.

I had just noticed it now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088486/error-a-function-definition-is-not-allowed-here-before-token)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

local function definitions are not allowed, change:

```
int main() {
void displaymenu(){
}
}
```

to this,

```
void displaymenu(){
  // ...
}

int main() {
  // ...
}
```